# Variable is still null after assign to object

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I'm currently building a simple application of example for Google Map API GeoCoding and stumbled upon a problem with javascript.

The geocodeRequest method should assign its result value to the variable this.tempResult.
However the varriable is null when I try to print it in Listener.

The output to console is:

- Listener: null
- geoCodeRequest: Object

The order how output is printed seems to imply that the code in Listener run ahead before the geoCodeRequest method manage to assign the this.tempResult variable.

Is there a solution for this?

```
$JSKK.Class.create
(
    {
        $namespace      :'application',
        $name           :'GeoCoder'
    }
)
(
    {
    },
    {
        service :null,
        main    :null,
        geoCodeInput: null,
        geoCodeButton: null,
        reverseGeoCodeButton: null,
        reverseGeoCodeActive: null,
        callback :null,
        reverseCallback:null,
        tempResult: null,


        init: function(main, callback, reverseCallback)
        {
            this.main = main;
            this.callback = callback;
            this.reverseCallback = reverseCallback;

            this.service = new google.maps.Geocoder();

            this.geoCodeInput = $('#toolPannel div[data-resource=locator] input[data-action=input]');
            this.geoCodeButton = $('#toolPannel div[data-resource=locator] input[data-action=geocode]');

            this.reverseGeoCodeButton = $('#toolPannel div[data-resource=locator] input[data-action=reversegeocode]');
            this.reverseGeoCodeActive = false;

            this.createListener();
        },


        geoCodeRequest: function(request)
        {
            this.service.geocode
            (
                request,
                function (result,status)
                {
                    //console.debug(arguments);
                    if (status== google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
                    {
                        this.tempResult = result[0];
                        console.debug(this.tempResult);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert ('GeoCoder request failed!');
                    }
                }.bind(this)
            );
        },

        createListener: function()
        {
            this.geoCodeButton.click(function()
                {
                    this.geoCodeRequest
                    (
                        {
                            address: this.geoCodeInput.val()
                        }
                    );
                    this.callback(this.tempResult);
                }.bind(this)    //Bind here
            );

            this.reverseGeoCodeButton.click(function()
                {
                    if (!this.reverseGeoCodeActive)
                    {
                        this.main.map.setOptions({draggableCursor:'crosshair'});
                        this.reverseGeoCodeActive=true;
                    }
                    else if(this.reverseGeoCodeActive)
                    {
                        this.main.map.setOptions({draggableCursor:'hand'});
                        this.reverseGeoCodeActive=false;
                    }
                }.bind(this)
            );

            google.maps.event.addListener
            (
                this.main.map,
                'click',
                function (event)
                {
                    if (this.reverseGeoCodeActive)
                    {
                        this.geoCodeRequest
                        (
                            {
                                location: event.latLng
                            }
                        );
                        console.debug(this.tempResult);
                        this.reverseCallback(this.tempResult);
                    }
                }.bind(this)
            );
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: Suggestion: pare this down. That's a lot of code. Further, you have not provided a way for someone else to reproduce the problem easily and investigate themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this code:

```
geoCodeRequest: function( request ) {
    this.service.geocode( request, function( result, status ) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            this.tempResult = result[0];
            console.debug( this.tempResult );
        } else {
            alert( 'GeoCoder request failed!' );
        }
    }.bind(this) );
},

this.geoCodeButton.click( function() {
    this.geoCodeRequest({
        address: this.geoCodeInput.val()
    });
    this.callback( this.tempResult );
}.bind(this) );
```

(Sorry, but I took the liberty of reformatting so I could follow the logic better. Feel free to convert back to your own style.)

You are trying to call `this.callback()` before the geocoded result comes back from the server. That won't work. You need to handle the geocoding result in the callback that the geocoder uses.

You're already providing the geocoder a callback in the `geoCodeRequest()` method, so what you can do is add a callback to your click handler and call that from the callback in `geoCodeRequest()`. You could do that like this:

```
geoCodeRequest: function( request ) {
    this.service.geocode( request, function( result, status ) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            request.success( result[0] );
        } else {
            request.failure( status );
        }
    }.bind(this) );
},

this.geoCodeButton.click( function() {
    this.geoCodeRequest({
        address: this.geoCodeInput.val(),
        success: function( result ) {
            console.debug( result );
            this.callback( result );
        },
        failure: function( status ) {
            alert( 'GeoCoder request failed!' );
        }
    });
}.bind(this) );
```

Note that I also added a failure callback to handle the error condition.

The `reverseGeoCodeButton.click()` handler has the same problem and can be fixed with the same solution.

This is close to your original approach, but I have to wonder if the code could be simplified. Do you need these multiple levels of code? In any case, wherever you're dealing with an asynchronous result like what the geocoder gives you, you do have to handle that inside the appropriate callback instead of after the geocoder (or any asynchronous function) returns.

Comment: Many thanks, that solve the issue. This is pretty much a training with using JSKK, so I try to build a clear structure for better understanding.